# importing CSV with special characters to MySQL table using PHP function fgetcsv()

Tags: php, mysql, csv, import, utf-8

in the CSV file itself, special characters are appearing. but when the file is imported to the database, the special characters (äÄ, öÖ, üÜ, ß) aren't stored correctly.
I'm using this code to import the file:

```
  $handle = fopen ('../csv/file.csv', 'r' );

  while ($data = fgetcsv ($handle, 1024, ';')) {
    $data = array_map('utf8_encode', $data); 
    $num = count ($data);
    for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
    }

    $col_1 = $data[0];
    $col_2 = $data[1];
    $col_3 = $data[2];
    $col_4 = $data[3];

    $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_name (Col_1 , Col_2, Col_3, Col_4) 
                                    VALUES (:ncol_1, :ncol_2, :ncol_3, :ncol_4)");
    $stmt->execute(array(
       'ncol_1'   => $col_1,
       'ncol_2'   => $col_2,
       'ncol_3'   => $col_3,
       'ncol_4'   => $col_4,
     ));

   }
```

in the database, the table and every column from the type "varchar" have the collation of utf8_general_ci

Comment: you can try insert to a temporary table with  utf8mb4 collation

Comment: Do not transfer data via Php, import it directly from the file into the table using LOAD DATA statement (this stmt execution is the only thing which should be made in PHP).

Comment: @Akina I was doing it like that actually, and it was working great, on the localhost, but on the server, the LOAD DATA is disabled, and I'd need SUPER user Privileges to enable it which is not an option

Comment: Does your MySQL account have FILE privilege? if so you may load the whole file into variable (using LOAD_FILE() function) and parse it to separate rows in stored procedure (for version 8 - in recursive CTE). Of course this is slower than LOAD FILE but much faster than row-by-row copying. If not then you may load the whole file as binary one, and provide it to stored procedure which will parse/save data - this does not need in FILE privilege even.

Comment: @Akina unfortunately it does not